# Как ускорить компиляцию программы на C++ в среде разработки Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, компиляция, codeblocks

Использую среду разработки Code::Blocks для изучения программирования на C++, при этом даже небольшие программы компилируются достаточно долго (10-15 секунд). В основном это происходит при использовании циклов for

Comment: И вообще, такая скорость компиляции - это нормально? Может быть это особенность данной IDE? Или же другие среды разработки работают с аналогичной скоростью?

Comment: антивирус отключите...

Comment: @pavel Не вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

покажите пример программы, сообщите конфигурацию своего компьютера (память, процессор, ос, ssd или hdd), покажите настройки сборки

- может вы в 1 ядро собираете (IDE СLion, кстати, автоматически использует передает компилятору все ядра)
- может быть у вас оптимизация включена максимальная, что всегда тормозит билды.
- может быть в Code::Blocks есть настройка использовать прекомпилированные заголовки (IDE DevShed C++ и его потомки компилируют их при установке, как насчет CB - не знаю)
- может быть у вас неправильно настроена система сборки и вместо того, чтобы компилировать только изменившиеся файлы, вы компилируете вообще все файлы подряд.
- идея насчет антивируса, кстати, неплоха, вполне можно включить каталоги с include-файлами, компилятором и ide в список исключений

IDE тут не при чем, code::blocks на виндоус использует mingw-версию gcc, если  мне память не изменяет (как почти все свободные IDE).  Скорость его работы в винде мне не очень известна, но можно поискать.

Вы можете попробовать подключить [бесплатную](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) версию  компилятора от Microsoft, или подключить [clang](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html), который обычно компилирует быстрее gcc

Если вы на винде, можете попробовать разобраться сами, с помощью, например  [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor). Увидите, что делает компилятор и в какие моменты что тормозит.